# Why properties you add to a custom .NET user control appear bold in propertygrid?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls, properties

Usually, only modified control properties are bold.

But in this scenario, I've created a custom user control and added a public property to it. When I add it to any container and open the properties window, all properties I've added appear also bold - despite the default value.

Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the [`DefaultValueAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) to the properties and set it to the value that you don't want to appear bold.